# Db2: perfomant way to check if item exists

Tags: sql, db2

what will be the fastest way to check if a specific item exists in table or not.

```
Select count(*)
From xyz 
where col = „xyz“
Group by col
```

I am evaluating the result of this select, but will be there a faster and Performance way?

Comment: _specific item_? Your query doesn't look for a specific item.

Comment: See EXISTS for the actual test: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=predicates-exists-predicate Your query does not test anything specific. It is more about writing an efficient, likely index-supported query.

Comment: Yeah just updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you want to do with the result.
It's generally not recommended to use aggregate functions, since you don't need to scan all matches - you need just one of them at most.

If it's some procedure logic:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE V_RES INT;
  
  -- You get 1 or NULL in the V_RES variable
  SELECT 1 INTO V_RES
  FROM SYSCAT.SCHEMATA
  WHERE SCHEMANAME LIKE 'SYS%'
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;

END@
```

If it's just a result of a single query:

```
SELECT
CASE 
  WHEN EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1
    FROM SYSCAT.SCHEMATA
    WHERE SCHEMANAME LIKE 'SYS%'
  )
  THEN 'YES'
  ELSE 'NO'
END AS RES  
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```